# Put a break in javascript function

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, caml-query

I have 10 SharePoint lists.structure, column name, data type all are same.
I need to check whether a particular item is found in any list then do some action using ECMAScript.

```
     var arraylist=["A","B",.......];
     for(var i=0;i<arraylist.length;i++)
       {
        //using caml query here and loading collection

       }
      clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

      function onQuerySucceded()
      {
       var count=this.colllistitem.get_count();
       if(count!=0)
       //**How can I put a break here?.Item exists..I dont want any more iteration..**
      }
```

how can I apply a break there? I don't want any further iteration of ArrayList.

Comment: If you declare a global variable which you set when `count!=0` and then test it on your iteration to stop it, does it work?

Comment: ok.I will give it a try.